# Valid JSON with status 200 always returns 404 on the application

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs, jsonp

I've spent hours and hours in this problem and I can't get it working.

The problem is as follows:

I have to fetch a JSON from a certain address. I have validated that server's response and it is a valid JSON. On top of that, it works just fine as far as my network is concerned.

(I'd put an image proving it if I had enough reputation hehe)

On my client-side application, though, I keep getting a 404 code.

Here is my code:

```js
(function(){
 var app = angular.module('queryApp', ['ngRoute'])

 .controller('queryController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http){

  this.inputChange = function (){
   $http.jsonp('http://localhost:3000/orders?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').
    success(function(data, status){
     console.log(status)
    }).
    error(function(data, status){
     console.log(status)
    });
  };

 }]);

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="queryApp">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

  <!-- Roboto Font -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  
  <!-- Twitter Bootstrap -->
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- custom stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/search.css" type="text/css">

 </head>
 <body ng-controller="queryController as query">

  <form class="form-search">
   <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Looking for something?" ng-model="input" ng-change="query.inputChange()">
  </form>

  <h1>{{input}}</h1>


  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- AngularJs -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Search App -->
  <script src="app/app.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

The funny thing is if I change the URL of the request to, let's say, the one on the AngularJS JSONP tutorial (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) it works just fine! I can simply fetch the data. Having said that, I repeat: the JSON I'm trying to fetch IS valid.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It is probably because your api call is not supporting jsonp, i.e it does not return wrapped(callback) object. But i am not sure if you will get 404 for that though

Comment: Yeah the code that is going to be important here is your server code. Post that for us.

Comment: I was about to say the same. Do you really need jsonp anyway? since it's localhost, try a `$http.get` instead

Comment: Why do you use full url (`http://localhost:3000/orders...`) instead of relative (`/orders...`)? If your html page is not loaded from the same origin (localhost:3000), then you may want to read about [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: I had to use it that way because the server runs in an specific port and for some reason it wouldn't allow me to access it via GET. PSL, you're right. I figured that out 5 minutes after I posted even though I spent many many hours trying to solve it before. I guess writing the problem helped me realise that. Thanks for your help by the way!